# How to filter Django model for AND and OR simultaneously

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

Let's say I have a User model and a Dataset model. I want to get all datasets that (have a certain type AND (belong to a certain user OR don't belong to anyone)). What is the best approach to achieve this?

Code sample:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True,)
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)


class Dataset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=50)
    type = (models.PositiveIntegerField())
    UserID = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="ds_owner",
    )
```

I am trying to figure out how to select something like this:

```
def view_name(request):
    usr = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id) 
    allowed_datasets = Dataset.objects.filter(type=1 AND (UserID=usr OR UserID__isnull=True))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`Q`** objects <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) to present filtering options as object, and then use `&` and `|` for conjunctions and disjunctions.

You thus can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Q


def view_name(request):
    usr = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    allowed_datasets = Dataset.objects.filter(
        Q(type=1) & (Q(UserID=usr) | Q(UserID=None))
    )
```

or shorter:

```
from django.db.models import Q


def view_name(request):
    usr = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    allowed_datasets = Dataset.objects.filter(
        Q(UserID=usr) | Q(UserID=None), type=1
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.